# Can't Call web service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, c#-4.0

Hi I am trying to call this web service:
https://knockknock.readify.net/RedPill.svc

I go to Visual studio ,right click to references and chose add service references and put the URL everything is fine but I can't take an object from this service class like in weather service :

```
weather.GlobalWeatherSoapClient
weather=new weather.GlobalWeatherSoapClient();
```

thanks

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: web service namespace not exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readify asks to develop a web service which references https://knockknock.readify.net/RedPill.svc and implements IRedPill interface.
This means you need to create a WCF service which references redpill service and uses IRedPill interface as a ServiceContract. You do not need to create a client/proxy of the service. There is no method there to call.

Instead do this.

```
public class Class1 : IRedPill
{
    //implement interface here
}
```